# List of UUID libraries for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a list of UUID gems for Ruby on Rails, could someone please recommend a couple to me, preferably ones that are not so complicated that I wouldn't be able to understand them easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UUID) is a nice place to start your search.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to use [UUID Tools](http://rubygems.org/gems/uuidtools)

A brief of what they offer:

> UUIDTools was designed to be a simple library for generating  any of
>   the various types of UUIDs. It conforms to RFC 4122 whenever possible.

I have been using it for different projects and I haven't had any problems.  Also, the documentation is pretty good. Check this out for more reference [UUID Tools Reference](http://uuidtools.rubyforge.org/)